# Flutter getting data from a map API

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dictionary, get

hi am new to flutter and i need to get data from a map using API I m struggling at the moment and don't know what to do I always keep getting a error Error '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'
this is the class  code

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final aziz = azizFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Demandes azizFromJson(String str) => Demandes.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String azizToJson(Demandes data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Demandes {
  Demandes({
    required this.srMboSet,
  });

  SrMboSet srMboSet;

  factory Demandes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Demandes(
        srMboSet: SrMboSet.fromJson(json["SRMboSet"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "SRMboSet": srMboSet.toJson(),
      };
}

class SrMboSet {
  SrMboSet({
    required this.rsStart,
    required this.rsCount,
    required this.sr,
  });

  int rsStart;
  int rsCount;
  List<Sr> sr;

  factory SrMboSet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SrMboSet(
        rsStart: json["rsStart"],
        rsCount: json["rsCount"],
        sr: List<Sr>.from(json["SR"].map((x) => Sr.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rsStart": rsStart,
        "rsCount": rsCount,
        "SR": List<dynamic>.from(sr.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Sr {
  Sr({
    required this.rowstamp,
    required this.attributes,
  });

  String rowstamp;
  Attributes attributes;

  factory Sr.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Sr(
        rowstamp: json["rowstamp"],
        attributes: Attributes.fromJson(json["Attributes"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rowstamp": rowstamp,
        "Attributes": attributes.toJson(),
      };
}

class Attributes {
  Attributes({
    required this.ticketid,
    required this.attributesClass,
    required this.description,
    required this.status,
    required this.statusdate,
    required this.reportedby,
  });

  Class ticketid;
  Class attributesClass;
  Class description;
  Class status;
  Class statusdate;
  Class reportedby;

  factory Attributes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Attributes(
        ticketid: Class.fromJson(json["TICKETID"]),
        attributesClass: Class.fromJson(json["CLASS"]),
        description: Class.fromJson(json["DESCRIPTION"]),
        status: Class.fromJson(json["STATUS"]),
        statusdate: Class.fromJson(json["STATUSDATE"]),
        reportedby: Class.fromJson(json["REPORTEDBY"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "TICKETID": ticketid.toJson(),
        "CLASS": attributesClass.toJson(),
        "DESCRIPTION": description.toJson(),
        "STATUS": status.toJson(),
        "STATUSDATE": statusdate.toJson(),
        "REPORTEDBY": reportedby.toJson(),
      };
}

class Class {
  Class({
    required this.content,
  });

  String content;

  factory Class.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Class(
        content: json["content"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "content": content,
      };
}
```

and this is my main code I always get  a error if anyone can help please

```
// ignore_for_file: use_key_in_widget_constructors, avoid_print, avoid_unnecessary_containers, curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures, prefer_const_constructors, non_constant_identifier_names, unnecessary_new, avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls
import 'dart:convert';
import './demandes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DataFromAPI(),
    );
  }
}

class DataFromAPI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataFromAPIState createState() => _DataFromAPIState();
}

class _DataFromAPIState extends State<DataFromAPI> {
  List<Attributes> MyAllData = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    loadData();
  }

  loadData() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'http://192.168.1.30:9080/maxrest/rest/mbo/sr/?_lid=&_lpwd=&_format=json'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String responseBody = response.body;
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonBody = json.decode(responseBody);
      for (var data in jsonBody) {
        MyAllData.add(Attributes(
            ticketid: data["ticketid"],
            attributesClass: data["attributesClass"],
            description: data["description"],
            status: data["status"],
            statusdate: data["statusdate"],
            reportedby: data["reportedby"]));
      }
      setState(() {
        MyAllData.forEach((somedata) => print("Name: ${somedata.ticketid}"));
      });
    } else {
      print("theres something wrong...");
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Liste des SR'),
        ),
        body: MyAllData.length == 0
            ? new Center(
                child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : showMyUI(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showMyUI() {
    return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: MyAllData.length,
        itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Card(
              child: new Container(
                child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'Ticket ID : ${MyAllData[index].ticketid}',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your model class, what I see is that you have `Attributes` inside of `Sr`, but after your JSON decode, you went ahead to just add data to the attributes list, so that's where your error is coming from, you have not fully deserialised the data here's how you can do it and it would work

```
      loadData() async {
        var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
            'http://192.168.1.30:9080/maxrest/rest/mbo/sr/?_lid=&_lpwd=&_format=json'));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final jsonBody = json.decode(response.body);
Demandes data = Demandes.fromJson(jsonBody);
final srAttributes = data.srMboSet.sr;
// SR is your list attributes is just an object, So what you do is this 
          for (int attribute = 0; attribute  < srAttributes.length; attribute++) {
MyAllData.add(srAttributes[attribute].attributes);

          }
          setState(() {
            MyAllData.forEach((somedata) => print("Name: ${somedata.ticketid}"));
          });
        } else {
          print("theres something wrong...");
        }
      }
```

Comment: i get this error "The argument type 'Sr' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'."

Comment: I have edited the code now I made a semantic error in my code

Comment: I/flutter ( 9050): [Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr', Instance of 'Sr',

Comment: This looks more like it, I have edited the code now it should work just fine for you now, do well to upvote the answer so you can help others.

Comment: dude is there anyway i can contact you  , I m really struggling and i will really appreciate your help , thank you in advance

Comment: Yeah sure my twitter https://twitter.com/m3st3r33ous

Comment: but why it only show instance of SR when there's data in the list sorry for asking too much

Comment: So SR is a class that holds a list of data that is and this data it holds is the "Sr" object, so what it is showing you, is the instance of the object in the List, which in this case is "Sr", I don't know if this makes sense to you.

Comment: you do but is there anyway i can fix it ?

Comment: It's not an error, it's just letting you know what's in the list.
Have you tried the edited code? 
Is it working for you now?

Comment: i cant message u on twitter can u ? we can talk better there

Comment: You should be able to send me a message